# Converting Bytes to String results in ? rather than £ (ASCII)

Tags: c#, encoding, byte

I have pulled a predefined message from a network stream and I convert it to a string using:

```
string payloadString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payloadBytes);
```

I have noticed from reading here: http://www.ascii-code.com/

that £ is only for ASCII extended (127+) and the one I am using above only covers non extended ASCII (0 - 127).

This results in some of my payload containing '?' rather than '£'.

Is there a way of converting the bytes using ASCII Extended encoding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Encoding.Default` (which is the system's default ANSI code page) or `Encoding.UTF8`, rather than `Encoding.ASCII`. In any case, check with whoever sends the message what the encoding is supposed to be, and use that.

Answer (score 1):

use   [`UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.encoding.utf8) Encoding object that encodes `Unicode` characters into a sequence of one to four bytes per character this  will ensure the right encoding of character

```
string payloadString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payloadBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code in:

```
string payloadString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payloadBytes);
```